# Detecting surface intersection in lispbuilder-sdl

Tags: sdl, common-lisp, collision-detection

I am working on making a game in Common Lisp, using Lispbuilder-SDL. I am currently writing a function to check for collision between two surfaces. I need to find out if a surface A intersects with another surface B. I haven't yet seen anything that fits the bill on https://lispbuilder.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/lispbuilder-sdl.html - is anyone aware of a simple, built-in way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The math for the line that forms when two planes/surfaces intersect is not difficult.  See [Intersecting Planes](http://mathinsight.org/intersecting_planes_examples), [Plane Geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29) or generally [Googling](http://bit.ly/127Y5qZ).  If there is no intersection, then the planes/surfaces are parallel - there are simple tests for that.

A plane is defined by a point and a normal.  If the dot-product of two plane normals is one, then the planes are parallel.  In your game, if the dot-product is close enough to one, then the intersection is outside of the play area.

Comment: Perhaps you meant the vector-product? If the dot-product is 0, then the normals are orthogonal or one normal is zero.